# Editing files in pub/static/frontend directory advisable?

Tags: magento2, theme

I want to edit CSS file in one of the project, I found using developer tools in Chrome that the file is located in pub folder. Is it advisable to edit it in `pub/static/frontend/Company/theme/en_US/css/` directory or it should be somewhere in `app/code/` or `vendor/` folder? If I change in `pub` directory, will it get overwritten at any point during static files deployment?

Same with any other files located in `pub/static/frontend`, is it reliable to change anything in that folder at all?

Answer (score 2):

No, you should not edit pub/static files. Because when you run setup upgrade all files will replace and your changes will not available.

if you are using developer mode, static files created automatically and if your mode is default you need to create static file using static: content deploy command.

If you are using default mode you can write your CSS in both files(original and from pub/static) so without content deploy you can see your changes and when static files get replace your changes still available from original CSS files.

If you are using developer mode, make CSS changes direct to original files.

Answer (score 2):

All the files in pub/static are automatically generated by Magento in several ways

Its can be copies or symlinks of all the files used in your store. There are files from your current theme and from the base theme according with the fallback hierarchy logic.

The best way to change your styles is from vendor/yourVendor/yourcurrentTheme. In developer mode the files will be changed also in pub/static folder.

To be sure to have symlinks in your pub/static folder delete all the file inside and type in your terminal:

```
bin/magento dev:source-theme:deploy --theme [Vendor]/[theme] --locale [locale]
```

Now you need something to compile less. You can use grunt (integrated in Magento) or some custom solution with gulp you can find around the web.

See the following:

```
pub/static/frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme>/<locale>/css/styles-l.less
pub/static/frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme>/<locale>/css/styles-m.less
```

This files includes all other less your store need.

So your task runner will watch for the changes on all the files included in this two files and two css `styles-l.css` and `styles-m.css` will be generated.

For additional info [see the docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-preprocess.html)